# How can I add a text box in javafx without moving the buttons

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a javafx program to show some textbox and buttons but everytime I add the textbox, it ends up shifting the buttons.

```
    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5));
    pane.setHgap(6);
    pane.setVgap(7);

    pane.add(new Label("Text1:"), 0, 3);
    pane.add(new TextField(), 1, 3);
    pane.add(new TextField(), 1, 3, 1, 1);
    pane.add(new Label("Text2:"), 2, 3);
    pane.add(new TextField(), 3, 3);
    pane.add(new Label("Text3:"), 4, 3);
    pane.add(new TextField(), 5, 3);

    Button bt1 = new Button("Button");
    bt1.setMinSize(70, 0);
    pane.add(bt1, 1, 4);
    Button bt2 = new Button("Button");
    bt2.setMinSize(70, 0);
    pane.add(bt2, 2, 4);
    Button bt3 = new Button("Button");
    bt3.setMinSize(70, 0);
    pane.add(bt3, 3, 4);
```

I want the text box to be closer to the label and the buttons to have less space between them.

Comment: I am guessing you need this add method. `add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, int colspan, int rowspan)`

Comment: How do you want to the final product to look?

Comment: I tried that but I still couldn't get it closer the label has too much space to the text field and I've tried that method on the label and the textfield. neither worked. using it on the text field just changes the size of it and using it on the label makes it move around too much.

Comment: buttons next to  each other without too much space, and right now none of the text fields overlap more than one button. it just adds white space if the text field is larger than the button but I want it to overlap so I can have a text field on top of two buttons instead of just one and a lot of white space.

Comment: Show an image of your current problem and an image of how you would like it to be.  SceneBuilder would be useful in figuring this out.

Comment: As Sedrick requested, [uploading the image(s)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) of your GUI may help us better understand the problem. I don't believe you have enough reputation to embed the image but you can post links; someone with enough reputation will likely come along and embed the images for you.

Answer (score 2):

A `GridPane` aligns nodes in the same row/column and (assuming no row/column spans except for 1 are used) makes sure nodes positioned in different rows/columns do not overlap the range of a node takes vertically/horizontally.

You're trying to align the `Label`s/`TextField`s and the `Button`s independently though which does not work, at least not unless you make things unnecessarily complex.

Instead of using a `GridPane`, I recommend simply using a `VBox` containing 2 `HBox`es instead:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    HBox textFieldContainer = new HBox(
            new Label("Text1:"),
            new TextField(),
            new Label("Text2:"),
            new TextField(),
            new Label("Text3:"),
            new TextField());
    textFieldContainer.setSpacing(6);
    textFieldContainer.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

    // add margin to all but the first Label/TextField pairs
    Insets innerLabelInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 20);
    List<Node> children = textFieldContainer.getChildren();
    for (int i = 2, size = children.size(); i < size; i +=2) {
        HBox.setMargin(children.get(i), innerLabelInsets);
    }

    Button bt1 = new Button("Button");
    bt1.setMinSize(70, 0);
    Button bt2 = new Button("Button");
    bt2.setMinSize(70, 0);
    Button bt3 = new Button("Button");
    bt3.setMinSize(70, 0);
    HBox buttonContainer = new HBox(bt1, bt2, bt3);
    buttonContainer.setSpacing(6);

    VBox pane = new VBox(textFieldContainer, buttonContainer);
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5));
    pane.setSpacing(7);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for